# How to save events in a day to database when user dragged in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using Django as backend. I want to save the events created by users to MySQL or SQLite database. [image: Screenshot]
How to actually create a list containing all the data?
e.g.

```
[
{
     "id":1,
     "title":"My Event 2",
     "time":$WhateverTimeFormat,
},
{
     "id":2,
     "title":"My Event 5",
     "time":$WhateverTimeFormat,
}
...
]
```

**Thank you so much!**
I am sure how to post and save this kind of data to the backend and database but it sucks when trying to create an array like this.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents

Comment: Ohhh I think I get the point, lol. Thank you so much!!